# Get DST Start and End Date for any Timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, dst

I see this question asked quite a bit, but don't see any actual answers (most solutions are for US time zone specifically).

Is there a way in SQL Server to get the start and end date of daylight saving time, given a year and a time zone?

To summarize, I'm looking to see if anyone has come up with a solution for the following two procedures/functions:

```
datetime2 getDSTStartDate(@year int, @timeZone varchar)
datetime2 getDSTEndDate(@year int, @timeZone varchar)
```

Comment: what about for locations that don't do DST... like the entire state of Arizona?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that it's not really possible to get exact days. There are country and regional differences, and some places don't even observe DST at all. It's *usually* on a prescribed date and time, but it can change during the year. Then your datetime calculations wouldn't matter.

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2017.html

See the second paragraph on that page:

> Note that this list might not be final - countries, territories, and
>   states sometimes make adjustments which are announced just days or
>   weeks ahead of the time change.

That statement alone would indicate that an internal database function could so easily become obsolete that it would be pointless.

You could do past dates, since they've already been completed, but as the below charts show, future dates, though somewhat set now, could change and would be impossible to accurately predict.

```
** Country Counts For Last 3 Years **
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                         **2017**                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                DST Observance                 |Count|Example|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|No DST at all                                  | 172 | China |
|At least one location observes DST             |  77 | USA   |
|All locations observe DST some part of the year|  67 | Iran  |
|Many locations observe DST part of the year    |   9 | USA   |
|At least one location observes DST all year    |   1 |       |
|All locations observe DST all year             |   1 | Chile |
---------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------
|                         **2016**                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                DST Observance                 |Count|Example|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|No DST at all                                  | 171 | China |
|At least one location observes DST             |  77 | USA   |
|All locations observe DST some part of the year|  69 | Iran  |
|Many locations observe DST part of the year    |   8 | USA   |
---------------------------------------------------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------
|                         **2015**                            |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|                DST Observance                 |Count|Example|
---------------------------------------------------------------
|No DST at all                                  | 168 | China |
|At least one location observes DST             |  80 | USA   |
|All locations observe DST some part of the year|  70 | Iran  |
|Many locations observe DST part of the year    |   9 | USA   |
|At least one location observes DST all year    |   1 |       |
|All locations observe DST all year             |   1 | Chile |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

***NOTE:** Because of the above vagaries, and because you'd also have to programmatically determine where your user made their entry, it would be better to just store datetimes in UTC or another universal format and consume it as needed. SQL may not be the best place for figure it all out.*

Comment: And to add to the fun, a note at the end of the big chart says: `* Some locations have multiple periods of DST: the start of the first period and end of the last period are listed.`